# How do you make the email field on the profile page read only for subscribers?

Tags: profiles, user-meta

I would like to make the email field on the profile page for subscribers read only. They can see their email but not change it. I want only admins to to be able to change users email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the readonly attribute can be removed using Chrome/Firebug inspector (making the field editable again), much probably the average user will not know this.

```
<?php
function wpse50730_script_enqueuer(){
    if(current_user_can('subscriber')) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            $(".form-table #email").attr("readonly", true);
        });     
        </script>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-profile.php', 'wpse50730_script_enqueuer');
```

Answer (score -1):

@brasofilo's answer is good, but better use .prop and the .user-email-wrap class to prevent impact on #email fields on other pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $(".user-email-wrap #email").prop('disabled', true);
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: @brasofilo's answer only hooks into the profile page and not into others. Every admin screen has a unique hook you can use and that's what you can see in that code.