# Prevent subscribers to changing certain profile fields

Tags: users, profiles

Is there a way to prevent "subscribers" from editing specific fields in their profile, like email?

I thought it would be simple enough, but I've read though quite a few posts about it around the web (including this one [prevent users from changing their email address](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/prevent-users-from-changing-their-email-address) and this [How do you make the email field on the profile page read only for subscribers?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50730/how-do-you-make-the-email-field-on-the-profile-page-read-only-for-subscribers)) and I have yet to find a solution that doesn't involve hacking the core code (not desirable imo) or just hiding/disabling the field by JS (which means someone could technically get past it in a number of ways).

But since most, if not all, posts I've found are a few years old so I'm thinking maybe something has happened since?

If it's not possible to prevent in a "pretty" way, are there any good alternatives? Can I prevent the "subscriber" user from accessing the profile at all and rather build a new form to let them change password?

The reason for this is that the email address (and possibly one or two other fields) will identify the users in a third party system, so it must only be changed by an administrator who can change it in both places.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `profile_update` hook.

[Codex link here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update).

It fires after updating, but supplies a copy of the old user data, so you can get the current email address, compare it with the old one and change back if necessary.

Comment: This could work as a safety net after disabling the field by jQuery. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong, users should be able to change their email when they stop using it and move to another. What you actually should do is generate a notification that an email address was changed so the admin can act on it and sync the other system, or better write some code that automatically does it.

Comment: In general, this isn't a bad idea at all, however it's not really suitable for this client. I'll definitely keep the idea in mind for future use though!